# nested swipers on the same axis get mixed up - trackpad only

Tags: swiper.js

If you nest swiper instances and don't set the nested swipers to move in a different direction (as the [demo does](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/11-nested.html)) then they seem to got mixed up on which one should be advanced when you swipe to next/prev.

UPDATE: This only happens when you use a trackpad - if you use a mouse it seems to work fine.

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/toru-sean/pen/reMNGg)**

So in my example I have set up a swiper with a `cube` effect and it then has four nested swiper instances, each with 3 slides. The nested instances have the default `slide` effect and have their `nested` options set to `true`.

So the desired effect is that you see the cube with an 'A' facing you, you then swipe to next and 'B' slides in, then the next wipe rotates the cube and you see 'C' on a different side - and so on.

This works most of the time, but every so often when you expect the nested slider to advance the parent slider does. So in my example you see the cube spin when it shouldn't.

I've tried to use javascript to lock the swipers when the swipe begins and then unlock when it ends but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I've just updated the question as i found that the codepen example works absolutely fine if you use a mouse, but breaks when you use either an Apple Magic Trackpad or the trackpad on a Macbook Air. It also works fine on mobile.